# Use L’Hôpital’s Rule to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{ (1+x)^{1/x} }e\right)^{1/x}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, applications

Use L’Hôpital’s Rule to evaluate $$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{ (1+x)^{1/x} }e\right)^{1/x}$$

I would like to use L Hopitals to find the limit.

My idea was using the fact that the limit of $(1+x)^{1/x}$ is e , as $x\to 0$, which leads to the indefinite expression $1^\infty$.

Not really sure how to tackle further.

Comment: This is not the type of problem to use L'Hopital

Comment: @trula It can be also solved by l'Hospital, but I agree, it is not the best way in this case.